# Why Is This ')' causing an error?

Tags: sql-server-2012

I want to create a stored procedure `spSumInvoices` that will take in the vendor id of interest and print out the vendor’s name and the sum of all their invoices.

This is the code I am using, not sure if its right I'm new to stored procedures:

```
IF OBJECT_ID ('spSumInvoices') IS NOT NULL
    DROP PROC spSumInvoices;
GO

CREATE PROC spSumInvoices
    @FindVen int,
    @InvoiceTotal Money,
    @VenName VARCHAR
AS
BEGIN  
    SELECT 
        @FindVen, SUM(InvoiceTotal) AS 'Total', @VenName
    FROM 
        Vendors,Invoices
    WHERE 
        Invoices.VendorID = @FindVen
    GROUP BY 
        @InvoiceTotal
END

PRINT 'Vendor' + @VenName
PRINT 'Has an invoice total of $' + CONVERT(VARCHAR,@InvoiceTotal);
```

I get this error:

> Msg 164, Level 15, State 1, Procedure spSumInvoices, Line 15
>   Each GROUP BY expression must contain at least one column that is not an outer reference.

Comment: Your `CONVERT` is missing the target data type parameter. You should remove it completely because you do not need it for `VendorName`.

Comment: If i put a data type which would be varchar it gives me this error: The name "VenderName" is not permitted in this context. Valid expressions are constants, constant expressions, and (in some contexts) variables. Column names are not permitted. @Filburt

Comment: Shouldn't you `SELECT VenderName,SUM(InvoiceTotal)` ... it's not clear where `Vendername`comes from.

Comment: Yes Hold on  Let Me Edit That I changed A few things around.  But it Gives me An Error :Msg 164, Level 15, State 1, Procedure spSumInvoices, Line 15
Each GROUP BY expression must contain at least one column that is not an outer reference. @Filburt

Comment: You need to `GROUP BY` a column, not a parameter. I'd suggest you sort out your query outside a sproc first.

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : declaring VARCHAR without (length)](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/09/bad-habits-to-kick-declaring-varchar-without-length) - you should **always** provide a length for any `varchar` variables and parameters that you use. In your case, the `@VenName` parameter will be treated as a string with a max length of **1 character** - hardly ever what you want ....

Comment: Hey man i appreciate the help but i got it all figured out.@marc_s

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to this question was:
   { USE AP;
    IF OBJECT_ID ('spSumInvoices') IS NOT NULL
    DROP PROC spSumInvoices;
    GO

```
CREATE PROC spSumInvoices
@FindVen int



AS
BEGIN
DECLARE @VenName Varchar(50);
SET @VenName =(SELECT VendorName FROM Vendors WHERE VendorID = @FindVen);
DECLARE @InvoiceTotal money;
SET @InvoiceTotal = (SELECT SUM(InvoiceTotal) FROM Invoices WHERE
VendorID = @FindVen);


SELECT @VenName,@InvoiceTotal
FROM Vendors,Invoices
WHERE Invoices.VendorID = @FindVen

END

PRINT 'Vendor ' + @VenName
PRINT 'Has an invoice total of $' + CONVERT(VARCHAR,@InvoiceTotal);
enter code here}
```